# Storing active row in a bit column vs. storing the logic in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a query where multiple factors determine the actual, active row. Can I do this in real-time and still be performant, or is an approach with a bit field the generally recommended approach, where the currently active field is indicated, index and queried?

My real-time solution involves an intermediate step in a view (temporary table in my example below). Therefore I am concerned about performance, because I will have to deal with hundreds of thousands to millions of records.

To illustrate:

```
DECLARE @grades TABLE (
    person int,
    grade int,
    attempt int,
    correction int)

INSERT @grades VALUES (1, 80, 1, 0)
INSERT @grades VALUES (1, 90, 2, 0)
INSERT @grades VALUES (1, 100, 3, 0)
INSERT @grades VALUES (2, 95, 1, 0)
INSERT @grades VALUES (2, 80, 1, 1)
INSERT @grades VALUES (2, 90, 1, 2)
INSERT @grades VALUES (2, 89, 1, 3)

SELECT b.*
INTO #grades_corrected
FROM @grades AS b
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT person, attempt, MAX(correction) AS last_correction
    FROM @grades as b
    GROUP BY person, attempt
)
AS last_corrections
ON (b.attempt = last_corrections.attempt
    AND b.correction = last_corrections.last_correction
    AND b.person = last_corrections.person
)

SELECT g.*
FROM #grades_corrected g
LEFT OUTER JOIN #grades_corrected g2 ON (
    g.person = g2.person
    AND g.grade < g2.grade)
WHERE g2.grade is null

DROP TABLE #grades_corrected
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  SQL Server has no concept of an "active" row.

Comment: Just my two cents: "...I will have to deal with hundreds of thousands to millions of records..." -- Perhaps SQL Server is not the right database for your case. Maybe you should consider upgrading to Oracle or DB2. As a general rule SQL Server is a "departamental database"; it's not high end by any means.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is going to be much more nuanced than just the sql you have.  In any case the sql you have above will breakdown most quickly on the group by with the max and the temp table copy.  Both of these will depend heavily on how many records are in the table and how much power (cpu and ram mostly) on your sql server.  If you copy "millions" of records into the temp table, it will most likely be slow by most standards.